# get list of activity of current package which was not finished

Tags: android

I have one confusion I want to get list of all activity which was not finished previously

My code is

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            for (RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo : taskInfo) {

                ComponentName comName=runningTaskInfo.baseActivity;
                String Packname = comName.getPackageName();
                String Classname = comName.getClassName();
                RunningServiceInfo s;
                Logger.debug("component name:"+comName+" packname:"+Packname+" class name:"+Classname);

            }
```

so this  code gives me only base activity name of stack where as

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            for (RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo : taskInfo) {

                ComponentName comName=runningTaskInfo.topActivity;
                String Packname = comName.getPackageName();
                String Classname = comName.getClassName();
                RunningServiceInfo s;
                Logger.debug("component name:"+comName+" packname:"+Packname+" class name:"+Classname);

            }
```

gives me top activity name..
but I want to get all activity name which was not finished so how to get those activity name??

Comment: At stackoverflow it's a good practice to accept answers to your questions, that you find useful. You can do this by clicking a check near the answer.